# How to remove 'X-Robots-Tag' http header in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, x-robots-tag

I am developing a project using the Symfony 5 framework. I have deployed that code to production. When I am trying to add website to google search engine then I am getting:

> Error "No: 'noindex' detected in 'X-Robots-Tag' http header"

I have changed the environment from dev to production but still I am getting the same error. I have tried to disable disallow_search index but this method is also not working

```
disallow_search_engine_index: false
```

How can change X-Robots-Tag header in Symfony 5?

Comment: Did you clear the cache on the server after updating the config?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the APP_ENV to prod in .env file like this:

```
APP_ENV=prod
```

And clear your cache with this command:

```
APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 php bin/console cache:clear
```

Apparently Symfony blocks search engines if it is in development mode

[source](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-automatic-search-engine-protection)

Comment: Muamet Islami Thank for replying.. i have already changed APP_ENV=prod , When i have tried to run 
```
APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 php bin/console cache:clear
```
i was getting error
APP_ENV is not recognized as an internerl or external command so i have run command without APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 but same issue exists

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you tried to disallow search engine index in the wrong file.

This worked for me:

`config/packages/framework.yaml`

```
framework:
    # ...
    disallow_search_engine_index: false
```